# Problems converting ps1 to exe using PowerGUI

Tags: powershell, powergui

I'm trying to convert my PowerShell project to an executable program (.exe). After some research I found PowerGUI. After converting my .ps1 file into an exe I ran into some problems:

**Firstly** it takes ages to start the program (about 15 seconds), is this normal or is there something I can do to improve this?

**Secondly**, if i exit the program I get a windows error message saying the program stopped working unexpectedly. Is there a way to hide this message?

Here is my ps1 code, I got a part of it from a blog and it is my first PowerShell code so don't be to harsh on me ;)

```
 $inputXML = @"
<Window x:Class="BlogPostIII.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BlogPostIII"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Organizer" Height="540" Width="540" FontSize="18.667">
    <Grid x:Name="background">
        <Button x:Name="OK" Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="41" Margin="420,458,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" FontSize="18.667"/>
        <Button x:Name="Cancel" Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="41" Margin="315,458,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" FontSize="18.667"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="108,216,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" FontSize="18.667"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="108,36,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Soort bewerking:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" FontSize="18.667"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBox2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="108,291,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" FontSize="18.667"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="108,111,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Naam Machine:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" FontSize="18.667"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBox3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="108,366,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" FontSize="18.667"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="108,185,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Naam van opdrachtgevend bedrijf:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" FontSize="18.667"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="108,261,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Naam product:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" FontSize="18.667"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="108,336,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Product ID:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" FontSize="18.667"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="combobox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="108,66,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="combobox2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="108,140,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
"@        

$inputXML = $inputXML -replace 'mc:Ignorable="d"','' -replace "x:N",'N'  -replace '^<Win.*', '<Window'


[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')
[xml]$XAML = $inputXML
#Read XAML

    $reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml) 
  try{$Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )}
catch{Write-Host "Unable to load Windows.Markup.XamlReader. Double-check syntax and ensure .net is installed."}

#===========================================================================
# Store Form Objects In PowerShell
#===========================================================================

$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | %{Set-Variable -Name "WPF$($_.Name)" -Value $Form.FindName($_.Name)}

Function Get-FormVariables{
if ($global:ReadmeDisplay -ne $true){Write-host "If you need to reference this display again, run Get-FormVariables" -ForegroundColor Yellow;$global:ReadmeDisplay=$true}
write-host "Found the following interactable elements from our form" -ForegroundColor Cyan
get-variable WPF*
}

Get-FormVariables

#===========================================================================
# List the Comboboxes
#===========================================================================

$WPFcombobox1.AddText('Draaien')
$WPFcombobox1.AddText('Frezen')
$WPFcombobox1.AddText('Slijpen')

$WPFcombobox2.AddText('Doosan 3100LM')
$WPFcombobox2.AddText('Doosan 123')
$WPFcombobox2.AddText('machine 3')
$WPFcombobox2.AddText('machine 4')
$WPFcombobox2.AddText('machine 5')


#===========================================================================
# Actually make the objects work
#===========================================================================


#$WPFMakeUserbutton.Add_Click({(Get-FormFields)})


$WPFOK.Add_Click({
    $1 = $WPFcomboBox1.Text
    $2 = $WPFcomboBox2.Text
    $3 = $WPFtextBox1.Text
    $4 = $WPFtextBox2.Text
    $5 = $WPFtextBox3.Text + " Werkblad"
    New-Item C:\Users\Bjorn\Documents\Powershell\$1\$2\$3\$4\ -Force -type directory
    Copy-Item C:\Users\Bjorn\Documents\Powershell\Test_werkblad.docx C:\Users\Bjorn\Documents\Powershell\$1\$2\$3\$4\
    Rename-Item C:\Users\Bjorn\Documents\Powershell\$1\$2\$3\$4\Test_werkblad.docx C:\Users\Bjorn\Documents\Powershell\$1\$2\$3\$4\$5.docx
    Invoke-Item C:\Users\Bjorn\Documents\Powershell\$1\$2\$3\$4
    Invoke-Item C:\Users\Bjorn\Documents\Powershell\$1\$2\$3\$4\$5.docx
    $Form.Close()})

$WPFCancel.Add_Click({
    $Form.Close()})


#===========================================================================
# Shows the form
#===========================================================================
write-host "To show the form, run the following" -ForegroundColor Cyan

function Show-Form{
$Form.ShowDialog() | out-null

}

Show-Form
```

Answer (score 1):

About the **15 seconds** I am not sure why. Could you give more details? You should add logging and put time stamp in every message... This way you should be able to locate slow part.

About **avoiding the error message**, you should surround your code with [try/catch](http://www.vexasoft.com/blogs/powershell/7255220-powershell-tutorial-try-catch-finally-and-error-handling-in-powershell). For example:

```
    [...]

    write-host "To show the form, run the following" -ForegroundColor Cyan

    function Show-Form
    {
     $Form.ShowDialog() | out-null
    }

    try
    {
     Show-Form
    }
    catch
    {
     $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
     # Show friendly message with error and/or log the error)
    }
```

After reading your code here is some extra **advice** that could be useful:

- Do not hardcode paths. (Like "C:\Users\Bjorn\Documents\Powershell\")
- Do you really need PowerShell? Sounds like C# WinForms would be better for this task.
- Store XML in a file and read it rather having it in code in $inputXML variable.

Comment: Thanks for the repley, I tried the try/catch methode but it didn't solve the problem. I will try C# WinForms, after some research I saw it is much easier to make an executable file with it. And I got the XML bit from some guys blog and made my code around it, this is why I did it this way.

Answer (score 1):

The 15 second pause is PowerShell initializing in the background. This is especially noticeable on Windows 7

CAVEAT: "compiling" PowerShell to EXE in most cases (PowerGUI included) is stuffing your original PS1 file inside a Self-extracting EXE. You could do the same with 7-Zip or WinZip.

A PowerGUI "compiled" EXE locks your script execution to whatever version or PowerShell + .Net you had on your DEV box. IOW: If you compile on a PC with PowerShell v4 but only use Write-host in your script (for example), the target PCs will need PowerShell v4+ for it to run!